# typo3 extbase > Get (unordered) records from repository > But get them in the order of the MULTIPLE sysfolders containing them in Backend

Tags: database, sorting, orm, typo3, extbase

## EXAMPLE

SYSFOLDERS IN TYPO3 BACKEND

```
sysfolder A
- tx_myextension_record 1

sysfolder B
- tx_myextension_record 2
```

OUTPUT ON THE WEBSITE

```
A
- record 1

B
- record 2
```

### PROBLEM

If the editor changes the order of sysfolder A and sysfolder B, 
   the order in the records from the repository should change, too.

SYSFOLDERS IN TYPO3 BACKEND

```
sysfolder B
- tx_myextension_record 2

sysfolder A
- tx_myextension_record 1
```

OUTPUT ON THE WEBSITE

```
B
- record 2

A
- record 1
```

### SOLUTION

SOLUTION IN SQL

```
   SELECT * FROM tx_myextension 
   LEFT JOIN pages ON pages.uid = tx_myextension.pid
   ORDER by pages.sorting ASC
```

SOLUTION IN ORM

```
???
```

### WHAT I DID SO FAR

In the repository of tx_myextension

```
class MyRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    ...

    public function findStuff() {
        ...

        $query->setOrderings(
            array(
                // *** This is what I'm looking for ***
                'pages.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,

                // This is not needed:
                // Sort the area records inside the sysfolders
                // 'sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING

            )
        );

        ...

    }
}
```

THIS CAUSES AN ERROR:

```
1355142232: 
The ColumnMap for property "pages" 
of class "MyExtension\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Area"
is missing.
```

THE SOLUTION IS USUALLY, TO INJECT THE MISSING REPOSITORY LIKE

```
class MyRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{

    /**
     * pages
     *
     * @var \I\DontKnow\Domain\Repository\WhatToPutHere
     * @inject
     */
    protected $pages = null;

    ...

    public function findStuff() {
        ...

        $query->setOrderings(
            array(
                // This is what I'm looking for
                'pages.pid' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING,
            )
        );

        ...

    }
}
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK, THE ERROR REMAINS:

```
1355142232: 
The ColumnMap for property "pages" 
of class "MyExtension\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Area"
is missing.
```

### ENVIRONMENT

- Typo3 7.6.21
- Extbase 7.6.22

Comment: What version of TYPO3 are you using?

Comment: Thanks for asking: Typo3 7.6.21, Extbase 7.6.22, updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with extbase then you have to "forget" about SQL and focus on your domain modeling.

If your domain model doesn't have a property named `page` (I prefer the singularity name `page` instead of `pages` since your model only can be storage on a single page) then any references to this relation in your repository will fail.

So to solve your issue you need to create a page model. In this case you don´t need to define any properties cause you don´t need any. But if you ever is going to need any then just add the properties and there getter methods to this model.

```
<?php
namespace Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

class Page extends AbstractEntity {}
```

Then in your other domain model, lets call it `\Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\MyModel`, you define the page relation. Just add below property and getter method.

```
/**
 * @var \Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\Page
 */
protected $page;

public function getPage()
{
    return $this->page;
}
```

To map `\Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\Page` to the database table `pages` and `\Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\MyModel`s property `page` to the database field `pid` we need a little TypoScript. You can store this TypoScript in `ext_typoscript_setup.txt` in the root of your extension.

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\Page {
                mapping {
                    tableName = pages
                }
            }
            Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Model\MyModel {
                mapping {
                    columns {
                       pid.mapOnProperty = page
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, since we have a relation to the page, it is possible to use this relations properties in your repository `\Uwe\SampleExtension\Domain\Repository\MyModelRepository`. You do not need to define all properties in your model for your repository to use them, only relations to other models.

```
public function findStuff() {
    ...
    $query->setOrderings(
        array(
            'page.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
        )
    );
    ...
}
```

I hope above helps you out.

---

If you ever needs to use custom queries then you always have the option to build them yourself with `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_*` methods or in TYPO3 version 8.5 and up the better query builder `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder`.

After you have made your query at it has returned an array of rows then you can use the data mapper `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapper`s `map` method to retrieve your models and there relations.

Please note that doing this manually might has some site effects and that there might be a lot of things that you will have to take care of manually! - I always tries to stick to the repository default options.

Comment: Hi Lasse, you pointed me in the right direction. I'll post the complete solution, when I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, looking forward to see your solution

Comment: It is throwing an error "
The relation information for property "xxxx" of class "yyy\zzz\Domain\Model\dddd" is missing."

Comment: @Ques Sorry, can't answer your question. I left typo3 some years ago, using wordpress, now. Good luck!

Comment: I know this worked back in version 7 and 8, I used it a lot. But I’m in the same boat as Ques and have not worked with TYPO3 since version 8 - new job = new framework. But I do miss it. My best advice for you would be to ask you question in the extbase slack channel - the community is awesome

Answer (score 0):

your *solution* in SQL is no solution. Because

```
SELECT * FROM tx_myextension 
ORDER_BY pages.sorting
```

will result in an SQL error as there is no relation between your table (`tx_myextension`) and the table `pages`.

For your sorting you need to build up a relation and then add all fields. you should not forget the ordering inside the pages.

```
SELECT * FROM tx_myextension 
       LEFT JOIN pages ON pages.uid = tx_myextension.pid
       ORDER by pages.sorting ASC, tx_myextension.sorting ASC
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, you are right, I have updated my post. Thank you.

Comment: you changed your SQL but did nothing to build that join also in the ORM. Without relation you can not use fields from another table.

Comment: Meanwhile I noticed some pitfalls: if your pages are not within the same parent page your sorting on the field `pages.sorting` can be chaotic, as any usage of a field `sorting` can only be used in that page context. you could sort your records (only) by their own `sorting` field, but that would mix the records in unpredictable orders on any change (of order) in either of the involved pages as this could renumber the sorting field of all records in that page.

Comment: The 'pages.pid' in $query->setOrderings() makes the ORM to create a JOIN command.

Comment: Sorting of records is not required.

Comment: `$query->setOrderings()` does not set any relations automagically. you need to define it. Look at the generated query  (SQL)

Comment: 2. Yes, maybe $query->setOrderings() doesn't do it. I don't know. To define a relation, I would use something like $query->matching($query->equals('pages.uid', 'pid')); This still leads to the error I get in the first place, because the $pages property is not defined, and I do not know how to define it. See the line /* @inject */ protected $pages = null; in my example code.

Answer (score 0):

As I Understand your Problem,
you have records of your domain model stored on multiple pages/sysfolders.
and want to display seperated by the source Page.

i would go a rather simple approach:

in your "plugin" you select multiple source Pages. the controller then interates 
over every source pages. and fetches records of your domain model with PidRestrictions.

this way your domain logic is a lot simpler. (but exbase performs multiple, database queries) . only optimize if you have a real performance problem. don't make thinks more complex if they don't have to be.